# How can I send e-mail using python and jinja?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, smtplib, email-templates

I'm trying to send an html email with python using jinja to insert strings into an html template. With the following code, I'm able to run my flask app on my local host and send an email, but the email does not send the template I want it to...in fact, it does not have anything in the email at all.

Here is an abbreviated version of the code I'm using:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from util import send_email

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    send_email("SUBJECT", "recipient@gmail.com", "CONTENT")
```

util.py

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from flask import render_template

def send_email(subject, recipient, content):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg["Subject"] = "SUBJECT"
    msg["From"] = "sender@gmail.com"
    msg["To"] = "recipient@gmail.com"
    msg.set_content(
        render_template("email_template.html", content=content),
        subtype="html"
    )

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port=465) as smtp:
        smtp.login("sender@gmail.com", "password")
        smtp.send_message(msg)
```

email_template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>email_template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> {{content}} </p>
    </body>
```

How can I get this to send the html template in an email with the content i want to insert in the template?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete solution myself yet but you could work with the jinja env already loaded in current_app

```
from flask import current_app

jinja_template = current_app.jinja_env.get_template("email_template.html")

html_content = jinja_template.render(content=content)
```